# Still unable to create node with FQDN for chef client configuration

Tags: chef-infra, knife

As has been reiterated time and time again, the FQDN is not available until at least one successful chef-client run. This is a minor pain, and I wondered if anyone had successfully found a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`hostname`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_hostname.html) resource.

depending how you utilize the `hostname` resource -- if you use it in conjunction with `compile_time` attribute set to `true`, then the `node['fqdn']` will be available in the [convergence phase](https://docs.chef.io/chef_client_overview.html). otherwise, use [lazy evaluation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#lazy-evaluation).